# Bootstrap datetimepicker in a div visible on mouseover

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the datetimepicker from bootstrap.
I have a table containing a list of items, and on each column, I have an input to make some search on each field from the items.
I have a field "creationDate" and I want to be able to search a date between two dates, so to take less space, i have an icon for this field which shows a div on ng-mouseenter which contains the 2 inputs with datetimepicker.

The code of this part is like this :

```
<td>
    <img src="/assets/css/images/unroll-icon.png" ng-mouseenter="showSelectCreationDate()" />
    <div class="selectCreationDate" id="selectCreationDate" ng-mouseleave="hideSelectCreationDate()">
        Date min. :
        <input type='text' data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" id='inputCreationDateMin' />
        <br />Date max. :
        <input type='text' data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" id='inputCreationDateMax' />
        <script type="application/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#inputCreationDateMin').datetimepicker({
                    pickTime: false
                });
            });

            $(function () {
                $('#inputCreationDateMax').datetimepicker({
                    pickTime: false
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>

</td>
```

The problem is that when I move my mouse in the datetimepicker popup, it is considered as a mouseleave from the div, so it disappears and I can't select the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that when you mouse over a id/class it hides your popup- try this:

```
    $(document).on("mouseover", "#nameOfyourField", function (e) {           
        //Do whatever you want to do
    });
```

Now if you click somewhere in the body of your web-page the popup will go away:

```
        $(document).on("click", "body", function () {
        $("#nameOfyourField").hide();
    });
```

I hope this is what you're looking for:

Comment: You seem to use some JQuery here. But I've made the almost same thing but with AngularJS which I use in my project.
Now it works, so thanks !